Can simulink and ndisplay with switchboard control ue at the same time?
I try to use ndisplay and switchboard display 3monitor
and then I open the simulink try to open the ue4.27
and then the monitor display loading
and finally the program crashed.
can it work together?
I try to use ndisplay and switchboard display 3monitor
